# How to join 2 datasets by looking up based on a string (full match or part match)

Tags: python, pandas

I have df1 and df2 datasets.
I've list of company in df1 and I've company and company code in df2

if df1 company contains the string (full match or part match) that matches with df2 then bring in company code from df2 to df1

**Example of DF1**

| company |
| --- |
| Amazon pvt ltd |
| Apple pvt ltd td |
| Microsoft pvt ltd |
| International Business Machines - IBM |

**Example of DF2**

| company | company code. |
| --- | --- |
| Amazon | 1001 |
| IBM | 1003 |
| Microsoft pvt ltd | 1004 |

**Expected results**

| company | company code |
| --- | --- |
| Amazon pvt ltd | 1001 |
| Apple pvt ltd |  |
| Microsoft pvt ltd | 1004 |
| International Business Machines - IBM | 1003 |